# Why do i get i:0#.w|domain\\username and within RunWithElevatedPrivileges domain\apppool?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When i do

```
Console.WriteLine(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
```

i get the following response:

```
i:0#.w|domain\\username
```

When i do

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    Console.WriteLine(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
});
```

i get

```
domain\appPoolAccount
```

without `i:0#.w|`... within the loginname.

Is someone able to explain why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prefix (i:0#.w|) before the username is just an internal code so that SharePoint can identity the type of authentication (w: windows auth, f: formsbased, etc...). The i in the code is to identify that it is a user. FYI if you would try to write out a group, the prefix would be c instead of i.

The fact that you don't have a prefix in elevatedprivileges is that this will always be the admin/pool-account which will always be a windows user -  so no need to add the prefix...

Comment: But one question: i have tested this this morning under SP 2010 and this does not happen there. Is this SP 2013 specific?

Comment: My guess would be that your 2010 machine is only configured for using windows authentication? I am not sure but i want to guide you to this link which has a thorough explanation about the claims prefixes: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how come this is answers the question!!

Answer (score 0):

The prefix (i:0#.w|) is for Claims Based Authentication, which is what your SharePoint 2013 Web Application is on, and without elevated privileges will resolve to the logged in account (which is claims based). But when you run with Elevated Privileges you run with the Application Pool user, which is a windows domain user in your case, which you will find in IIS on the server running SharePoint 2013.